# why sql server increment the Identity specification?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using sql server 2012, in my database I have set primary key on `userid` also I have set the Identity specification as follows:

- Yes,
- Is Identity Yes,
- Identity Increment 1, and
- Identity Seed 1.

[image]

I've only inserted 5 users and `userid` values are 1,2,3,4,5. I am sure that after doing this I didn't do any previous inserts, and no other sp or trigger are using this table. This is just a completly new table.

Now, when I tried to insert the 6th user it inserted `userid` as 1001, for 7th 1002, and for 8th it inserted 2002. Why did this numbering leap happened at `userid`?

Comment: This is a well known and documented issue. It happens when the server is restarted. Here is the MS connect issue on this topic. Notice it is closed as "be design". https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/alwayson-fail To be honest, it shouldn't make any difference as you will naturally have gaps anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Usually Gaps occur when:

```
1. records are deleted.
2. error has occurred when attempting to insert a new record (e.g. not-null constraint error).the identity value is helplessly skipped.
3. somebody has inserted/updated it with explicit value (e.g. identity_insert option).
4. incremental value is more than 1.
```

The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following:

`Uniqueness of the value` – Uniqueness must be enforced by using a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint or UNIQUE index.

`Consecutive values within a transaction` – A transaction inserting multiple rows is not guaranteed to get consecutive values for the rows because other concurrent inserts might occur on the table. If values must be consecutive then the transaction should use an exclusive lock on the table or use the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

`Consecutive values after server restart or other failures` –SQL Server might cache identity values for performance reasons and some of the assigned values can be lost during a database failure or server restart. This can result in gaps in the identity value upon insert. If gaps are not acceptable then the application should use a sequence generator with the NOCACHE option or use their own mechanism to generate key values.

`Reuse of values` – For a given identity property with specific seed/increment, the identity values are not reused by the engine. If a particular insert statement fails or if the insert statement is rolled back then the consumed identity values are lost and will not be generated again. This can result in gaps when the subsequent identity values are generated.

Also,

If an identity column exists for a table with frequent deletions, gaps can occur between identity values. If this is a concern, do not use the IDENTITY property. However, to make sure that no gaps have been created or to fill an existing gap, evaluate the existing identity values before explicitly entering one with SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON.

Also, Check the Identity Column Properties & check the Identity Increment value. Its should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Open your table in design view

Now check that Identity Seed and Identity Increment values are correct. If not then you must correct them.